# Get-AD Computer not match text file content

Tags: windows, powershell, server, active-directory

I want to get a list of all ad computers excluding the servers that are in a text file. Here's my code:-

```
$excludedServers = (Get-Content 
 "C:\Users\testuser\Documents\RdpDisconnectedSessions\ExcludedServers.txt").name #| Sort-Object
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where { $_.DistinguishedName -like "*Computers*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $excludedServers }  | Select-Object Name
```

Any advise please ?

Comment: Please try `$excludedServers = Get-Content "C:\Users\testuser\Documents\RdpDisconnectedSessions\ExcludedServers.txt"` With the following line to filter them out
`Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where { $_.DistinguishedName -like "*Computers*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -notin $excludedServers }  | Select-Object Name`

Comment: Does `$excludedServers` contain distinguished name values or just server names?

Comment: Hi, $excludedServer contains just the server names. 

@Crafty, i've tried your code, it still displays all the ad servers along withthe ones in the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `Get-Content` is not going to bring back objects so the `.name` portion is not going to work. If it's just a list of computernames, then simply change it to.

```
$excludedServers = Get-Content "C:\Users\testuser\Documents\RdpDisconnectedSessions\ExcludedServers.txt"
```

If it's a CSV with a name column, then you can do it a few ways. Sticking with the format you had this would work

```
$excludedServers = (Import-Csv "C:\Users\testuser\Documents\RdpDisconnectedSessions\ExcludedServers.txt").name
```

Now that you have your list of names, you can filter like this (assuming it is actually the names of the servers and not their distinguished name)

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where { $_.DistinguishedName -like "*Computers*" -and $_.name -notin $excludedServers }  | Select-Object Name
```